# What is the life cycle of consumers?

Tags: masstransit

Are message consumers created only once when bus starts, or every time when message of corresponding type appears at the endpoint?

I mean this method of subscribing to messages:

```
cfg.ReceiveEndpoint(host, "customer_update_queue", e =>
{
    e.Consumer<UpdateCustomerConsumer>();
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A new consumer instance is created for each message received on the endpoint. Once the message is consumed, the consumer instance is released (and if it's IDisposable, disposed as well).

Comment: Is it disposed even if DI container is used for resolving instance?!

Comment: If a DI container is used, the appropriate ConsumerFactory from the integration library should be used to ensure proper lifecycle management. Including support for the containers listed on the documentation site.